# why does nginx worker process CPU usage is not 100% under wrk stress test?

Tags: performance, nginx, tcp, linux-kernel, profiling

when doing Nginx stress test by running `test cmd: wrk -t1 -c40 -d50s http://127.0.0.1:80`, I find the worker process of Nginx is not using 100% CPU, it is only 70% (from `top` command). I have tried different wrk options like `-t10 -c400`, CPU usage can not pass 70%.

So I think the process is some how sheduled out due to some blocking call by kernel. But the bcc [offcputime](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/offcputime.py) tool's offcpu time flame graph only has 1ms off cpu event for a 50 second record for the Nginx worker process. I expect there will be 30% * 50 sec = 15 sec offcput event. How could this happen?

I have veried my measure tool like offcputime works correctly by recording command like `tar -xf ../clang+llvm-17.0.2-powerpc64-ibm-aix-7.2.tar.xz`.

Comment: How many CPUs do you have and how many is it running on?

Comment: @stark, there are 20 CPUs on system. The Nginx is configured to binding to only one core to ensure stable performance result by `worker_cpu_affinity` and there is only one worker in Nginx.